# Probability that a sample will contain a defect

Tags: probability, sampling

I just want to check my math on calculating the probability that a random sample will include a defective record.

I have a population of 20,000,000 records.

If there are 7,000 records of the 20,000,000 that have a defect, what is the probability that a 10% sample will contain 1 of the defects?

A 10% sample would include 2,000,000 records.

The probability of 1 record being one of the defective records is:

```
7,000/20,000,000 = .00035.
```

The probability of one of the samples Not being defective is:

```
(1 - .00035) = .99965.
```

The probability of 2 samples not being defective is:

```
.99965 * .99965 = .9993.
```

The probability of 2,000,000 samples Not being defective is:

```
.99965^(2,000,000) = 8.73 x 10^(-305).
```

The probability that at least one of the 2,000,000 samples is one of the 7,000 defects is:

```
 1 - .99965^(2,000,000)
```

which is very, very close to 100%.

What sample size would have a .999999 probability of having at least 1 of the 7,000 samples?

$$.999999 = 1 - .99965^{(SampleSize)}$$

A sample size approximately 39,465 would have a .999999 probability of including 1 of the 7,000 defects.

Comment: Exactly one, or at least one? (I'd think that the other one is actually more interesting)

Comment: You need to round calculated values *up* to obtain integral sample sizes, so your answer of $\log(10^{-6})/\log(0.99965) =39465.979\ldots$ should be rounded to $39466$. I'd say you have a pretty good approximation anyway :-). Perhaps more important is to realize that you must sample *independently* and *with replacement* to justify these calculations. Without replacement, the answer drops all the way to $39427$ (and your first calculation drops over 16 orders of magnitude to $4.34\times 10^{-321}$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help whuber.  I am interested in at least 1.

Comment: For the first part, if I remove the "with replacement" condition, the formula appears to be the product ∏ 1- 7,000/(20,000,000-n)] with n=0 to n=(2,000,000 - 1).  Any suggestions of how I can perform a calculation of the product with such large numbers?